# How to insert data into mysql in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Dear: Helper I try to insert data from mymodulenameValidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController class in validation.php. i want get some data to new table that i already created in mysql when my payment get way is complete but i can't insert anyone help me please?

this is my function

```
public function getOrderInfo($point_id){

        $insertData = array(
         'point_id'  => $point_id,
      );

 if (!Db::getInstance()->insert(_DB_PREFIX_."order_info", $insertData)) echo "errors insert data";
        exit();
    }
```

I errors insert data all time.

Comment: Could you please add your table `order_info` structure? Also, isn't there any error displayed other than `errors insert data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first error I see is that you use `_DB_PREFIX_` in front of your table name. You should not put a prefix, Prestashop will add it for you later in `insert()` method.

If there is still an error please, add the structure of your table in your question. Also add a `var_dump` of your `$insertData` array.

Comment: okay thanks i got error from _DB_PREFIX_ . after i remove my code work find